# Proof of a fact regarding uniformly convergent functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence

Denote the pointwise limit of $f_{n}(x)$ as $f(x)$. Define $M_n = sup_{x \ \in E} |f_{n}(x) - f(x)|$. Show that $f_n \to f$ uniformly iff $M_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

Not sure how to start. Any tips would be appreciated!I know I have to show both directions since it is an iff statement.

Comment: That is exactly just  the Definition of UC.

Comment: I need to prove it.

Comment: We never prove a chosen definition.

Comment: My instructor gave me this as an exercise and claimed I could prove it from the actual definition of uniform convergence. Where $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N$ and so on. Where the N depends only on epsilon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

In the initial definition, You just need replace the condition

$$(\forall x\in E)\;|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$
by its equivalent
$$\sup_{x\in E}\{|f_n(x)-f(x)|\}<\epsilon$$

Comment: Ahhhh that was the trick I was missing. Now it follows pretty closely from the definition. I see where it's all going to come from now. Thank you!

Comment: I'll accept it in a few minutes. It isn't letting me accept it right now.